# Ruby docker-api to mount volume

Tags: ruby, docker

How do I mount a host volume into docker with the ruby docker-api (https://github.com/swipely/docker-api) on runtime?

Basically, the `docker run -v path:path` functionality with this gem.

Answer (score 2):

The current `README` missed the part to explain on how to use the volumes with container. You should be fine to run with below command with container's folder  `/foo`

```
container = Docker::Container.create('Cmd' => %w[test -d /foo],
    'Image' => 'debian:wheezy',
    'Volumes' => {'/foo' => {}}
  )
```

If you need mount with local folder, update to `Volumes' => {'/foo' => '/local_foo'}`
You can refer the test case from:

[container_spec.rb](https://github.com/swipely/docker-api/blob/5c677411fa9ba9dbb4a52e378f48cac4f9abf9bc/spec/docker/container_spec.rb#L394)

Comment: This doesn't work. I get an error "json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type" when I try this with the local folder. I also checked with docker inspect and I saw that when I use the option -v it will add an entry under the Entry "Mounts" and with the info you provided it does it under "Volumes"

Comment: any helps from this https://github.com/swipely/dockly/blob/master/lib/dockly/build_cache/docker.rb#L61?

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for [docker-api gem](https://github.com/swipely/docker-api/) states this in its [README.md](https://github.com/swipely/docker-api/blob/master/README.md#containers):

```
require 'docker'

# Create a Container.
container = Docker::Container.create('Cmd' => ['ls'], 'Image' => 'base')

# Attach to the Container. Currently, the below options are the only valid ones.
# By default, :stream, :stdout, and :stderr are set.
container.attach(:stream => true, :stdin => nil, :stdout => true, :stderr => true, :logs => true, :tty => false)
# => [["bin\nboot\ndev\netc\nhome\nlib\nlib64\nmedia\nmnt\nopt\nproc\nroot\nrun\nsbin\nselinux\nsrv\nsys\ntmp\nusr\nvar", []]

# If you wish to stream the attach method, a block may be supplied.
container = Docker::Container.create('Image' => 'base', 'Cmd' => ['find / -name *'])
container.tap(&:start).attach { |stream, chunk| puts "#{stream}: #{chunk}" }
stderr: 2013/10/30 17:16:24 Unable to locate find / -name *
# => [[], ["2013/10/30 17:16:24 Unable to locate find / -name *\n"]]

# If you want to attach to stdin of the container, supply an IO-like object:
container = Docker::Container.create('Image' => 'base', 'Cmd' => ['cat'], 'OpenStdin' => true, 'StdinOnce' => true)
container.tap(&:start).attach(stdin: StringIO.new("foo\nbar\n"))
# => [["foo\nbar\n"], []]
```

Does this help? Can I ask why are you trying to use [docker-api](https://github.com/swipely/docker-api/)? Can't you just use [docker volumes (-v)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume)?

Comment: I really don't understand. Where is a local volume connected in the example that you provided? I only find stdout and stdin redirected in those examples?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Binds`:

```
'Binds'     => ['/local/folder:/container/folder']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use both Marcelo's and BMW's answers together to create a container with a working volume:

```
container = Docker::Container.create('Cmd' => %w[test -d /foo],
    'Image' => 'debian:wheezy',
    'Volumes' => '/container' => {},
    'Binds'     => ['/local:/container']
)
```